# Showing a function y solves the linear second order ode with ivc

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the ode

$
y''(t)+p(t)y'(t)+q(t)y(t)=g(t)
$

Where the functions $p,q,g$ are continuous on an interval $I$. Let $\phi_1(t),\phi_2(t)$ be linearly independent solutions of the associated homogeneous equation ($g(t)=0$). Then I want to show that

$
y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(s)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}g(s) ds
$

is a solution to the initial ode with initial value $y(t_0)=0, y'(t_0)=0$ on the interval I.

Theoretical this problem is straight forward. Plug $y(t)$ into the ode and see that it solves it. However after numerous tries I can not differentiate $y(t)$ twice nor even once without some mistake.

Comment: It obviously cannot be the solution as currently stated. Your expression for $y$ does not depend at all on $g$. Did you leave something off?

Comment: oh ye that's a mistake. the function g should be multiplied on the integrant

Answer (score 1):

Is there not another typo in $\quad y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(s)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}g(s) ds \quad$?

Example:$\quad p(t)=-\frac{2}{x}\quad$ ; $\quad q(t)=\frac{2}{x^2}\quad$ ;   $\quad g(t)=\frac{6}{x^3}\quad$ ; $\quad t_0=1$
$$y''(t)-\frac{2}{x}y'(t)+\frac{2}{x^2}y(t)=\frac{6}{x^3}$$
Independent solutions of the associated homogeneous equation : $\quad \phi_1(t)=x\quad$ , $\quad \phi_2(t)=x^2\quad$

With conditions $\quad y(t_0)=y'(t_0)=0\quad$ the solution of the ODE is : $\quad y=2x^2-3x+\frac{1}{x}$

$
\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(s)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}g(s) ds =
\int_{1}^t \frac{t^2s-ts^2}{s\:2\:t-s^2\:1}\frac{6}{s^3} ds =
\frac{6(1-t)t-3\ln|1-2t|}{4t} 
$

This is not equal to $\quad y=2x^2-3x+\frac{1}{x}\quad$

Hense, $\quad y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(s)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(t)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}g(s) ds \quad$ is false.

Comment: I'm a TA in this course and the professor has so far made mistakes on 4/5 week sheets so maybe there is a mistake on this one, but there is not a typo from my side.  One thing I notice is that p,q,g is not continoues on an interval containing zero. I can not find other mistakes

Comment: @Soren123 - Symmetry indicates at least one more typo: the denominator surely should be $$\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(t) - \phi_2(s)\phi_1'(\color{red}{t})$$

Answer (score 1):

With the corrected formula, $$y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(s)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(s)}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}g(s) ds \\= \phi_2(t)\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_1(s)g(s)ds}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)} - \phi_1(t)\int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(s)g(s)ds}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}$$

Let $$f_1(t) := \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_1(s)g(s)ds}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}\\f_2(t) := \int_{t_0}^t \frac{\phi_2(s)g(s)ds}{\phi_1(s)\phi_2'(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)}$$

So $y(t) = \phi_2(t)f_1(t) - \phi_1(t)f_2(t)$. Now,
$$y'(t) = \phi_2'(t)f_1(t) + \phi_2(t)f_1'(t) - \phi_1'(t)f_2(t) - \phi_1(t)f_2'(t)$$
But, $$\phi_2(t)f_1'(t)- \phi_1(t)f_2'(t) = \frac{\phi_2(t)\phi_1(t)-\phi_1(t)\phi_2(t)}{\phi_1(t)\phi_2'(t)-\phi_2(t)\phi'_1(t)}g(t) = 0$$
So $y'(t) = \phi_2'(t)f_1(t) - \phi_1'(t)f_2(t)$ and 
$$y''(t) = \phi_2''(t)f_1(t) + \phi_2'(t)f_1'(t) - \phi_1''(t)f_2(t) - \phi_1'(t)f_2'(t)$$
But,
$$\phi_2'(t)f_1'(t) - \phi_1'(t)f_2'(t)= \frac{\phi_2'(t)\phi_1(t)-\phi_1'(t)\phi_2(t)}{\phi_1(t)\phi_2'(t)-\phi_2(t)\phi'_1(t)}g(t) = g(t)$$
So $y''(t) = \phi_2''(t)f_1(t) - \phi_1(t)''f_2(t) + g(t)$

Thus $$\begin{align}y''+py'+qy &=\phi_2''f_1 - \phi_1''f_2 + g + p(\phi_2'f_1 - \phi_1'f_2) + q(\phi_2f_1 - \phi_1f_2)\\
&=(\phi_2'' + p\phi_2' + q\phi_2)f_1 -(\phi_1'' + p\phi_1' + q\phi_1)f_2 + g\\
&=0f_1 - 0f_2 +g\\&=g\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, I just found were the mistake was. But meanwhile you post the right answer. It was easy to see that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ must be switched without changing the integral. There are only two possiblities. After checking, the only consistent one is $\phi_1(s)\phi'_2(s)-\phi_2(s)\phi'_1(s)$

Comment: @JJacquelin - actually, I noticed that Soren123 had edited to correct the formula (which was different from my suggestion in a comment to your post - I had assumed that $t$ was supposed to appear in the denominator).  So I tried out the new formula, and saw that it worked.